# Copying and Referencing of NSObjects iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

So for a while I have been working on this app - in which contains a folder-like structure of objects which have properties of arrays that can contain the same type of object, which in turn can contain more of this object, etc. These objects are called groups. In a shared data class I have a mater group object called mainGroup, and a property of my data class called selectedGroup to facilitate the display of data. These group objects can be modified, so for a considerable chunk of time I tried to develop a solution for getting the path through all of the arrays to the desired object, all the while having no clue about copying and that assigning one array equal to the other does not create a deep copy, just some kind of reference. The code was logically sound, but in it after a while I noticed that deleting things in the selectedGroup’s array property had the same effect on the actual master copy, which did some wonky things to my app.

I did some googling and figured out that I was not actually creating a whole new array, just referencing it some how. I’m still confused on this next part though. I thought that setting one array equal to the other would have the same effect as calling copy on it - and when I replace or delete objects in one array the other is affected. So what exactly is the compiler doing when you set two arrays equal to each other? Shouldn’t it just populate the new array with the pointers to the objects in the old array, not just reference the array itself? And how come that when doing this same operation with objects such as NSStrings you do not see the same effect? Lastly, what other objects have this same behavior as the NSArrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what exactly is the compiler doing when you set two arrays equal to each other?

A number of immutable classes in Objective-C implement `-copy` such that the method simply retains the original object and returns a pointer to it. For example, if you copy an instance of `NSString`, you'll get back a pointer to the same object. Because the object is immutable, it doesn't matter whether you actually make a copy of it or not -- the object can't change, and a copy would be exactly the same, so another pointer to the original object works exactly the same way the copy would. Retaining the object again ensures that the object won't be destroyed at least until the caller is done with the object.

The same is true of other classes, such as `NSArray` and probably `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, and perhaps others. A comprehensive list isn't really necessary since the behavior should be transparent to clients.

It's hard to understand how the problems you describe could crop up if you're really using an instance of `NSArray`. You can't add or remove objects from a `NSArray` -- that's what it means for the class to be immutable. It sounds like you're actually dealing with a mutable array (`NSMutableArray`), and that class (along with others like `NSMutableString`, etc.) do make actual copies when you call `-copy`.

It sounds like you haven't actually been making copies of the arrays you're using, but instead only copied the pointers to the arrays. For example:

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", nil];
NSArray *array2 = array1;
```

Now, the code above does *not* make a copy of the first array. What you've got there is a single array, with two variables that point to it. If you make a change to `array1`, you'll see that change reflected in `array2` as well because `array1` and `array2` are really just two names for the same array. If you want a copy, you can do this:

```
NSArray *array3 = [array1 copy];
```

Now, let's make a change:

```
NSLog(@"Size of array1: %ld", [array1 count]);  // 2
NSLog(@"Size of array2: %ld", [array2 count]);  // 2
NSLog(@"Size of array3: %ld", [array3 count]);  // 2

[array1 removeObjectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@"Size of array1: %ld", [array1 count]);  // 1
NSLog(@"Size of array2: %ld", [array2 count]);  // 1
NSLog(@"Size of array3: %ld", [array3 count]);  // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that that's simply how objects work. Whenever you are using an object, it's going to pass a reference to the former object, not copy it and create a new one, and NSArray's are objects themselves. If you want to do what you're saying in the question, you will need to create a new array and iterate through each individual object within the array and copy it into the new array. If you're using objective-c, you don't have anything else with this capability, although you can look around NSArray to get the functionality you want. If you are using swift, you can simply make arrays (look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)).